Entity Framework Extensions Bulk Insert
We are currently using Entity Framework Extensions to do bulk inserts which works great but I was looking into the possibility of turning some of our SQL tables into memory optimised tables.
Upon doing some regression testing, part of our .NET application failed as under the hood it is using a MERGE statement to bulk insert the data into the database which you you can't do with memory optimised tables.
Am I right in thinking it uses a MERGE statement under the hood due to includeGraph being true, which is non-negotiable I think, due to inserting a parent object with child objects attached?
_bulkInsertDb.BulkInsert(foo, inlcudeGraph:true);

Don't use those extensions for ETL to begin with. They aren't part of EF, aren't produced by Microsoft and as you found out, don't do what they claim. On the other hand, the very idea of doing a "bulk insert" to a memory optimized table is wrong. Bulk Insert has a very specific meaning - it means performing a minimally logged INSERT, the way BCP, BULK INSERT or SqlBulkCopy do. In this case instead of writing transaction log entries for each row, the entire data page is logged. That has no meaning in in-memory tables though. The locking mechanism itself is completely different

I strongly advise checking SQLBulkCopy & InMemory tables from dba.stackexchange.com. Yes, you can use SqlBulkCopy BUT in-memory tables aren't a "go fast" feature. They exist to reduce locking in high contention data, not to improve performance. If you have blocking issues due to bad queries or missing indexes, in-memory tables won't fix them. The database already buffers data aggressively

How many thousands of rows are you trying to import at a time? Where do they come from? SaveChanges has no performance problems if used properly to store the few dozen application objects typically involved in a business use case. It will store all pending changes in a single database transaction and usually with a single batch. For ETL or import jobs ORMs like EF are the wrong tool - like using  tweezers to dig a hole one dirt grain at a time. Loading multiple CSV files into staging tables using eg CsvDataReader and SqlServer.WriteToServer is equivalent to using a backhoe

Bulk insertion with MERGE used will cause blocking issues. As I see the MERGE could set table level lock.


Am I right in thinking it uses a MERGE statement under the hood due to includeGraph being true, which is non-negotiable I think, due to inserting a parent object with child objects attached?

Whenever a value has to be outputted, a MERGE statement is used to use the OUTPUT clause with the current index to be able to set the value to the right entity. This is often the case when outputing the identity value of the parent/child object when using the IncludeGraph option.
